# How to group a class by date and select Max(Date), primary-key and foreign-key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to reduce data from a class as given below (PK ... primary key, FK ... foreign key):

[image]

Using linq I tried several variations as given below

```
var groupedClass = from record in records
               group new {
                   record.Date
               }
               by new{
                   record.FK,
                   //record.PK  //  when included then resulting data are not distinct regarding FK
               }
               into g
               select new{
                   MaxDate = g.Max(r => r.Date),
                   SelectedFK = g.key.FK,
                   //SelectedPK = g.key.PK    // gives an error when PK is not inluced in by new
               };
```

but I can not get distinct PK, FK and Max(date) into the grouped data set. Please help!

Comment: How it is related to EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `FK`, then use [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-maxby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) to select the record with the maximum date in each group:

```
var groupedClass = records
    .GroupBy(record => record.FK)
    .Select(grp => grp.MaxBy(record => record.Date));
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Pe4Z4

---

If you're not using .NET 6 then `MaxBy` won't be available, so you could use `OrderByDescending` and `First` instead:

```
var groupedClass = records
    .GroupBy(record => record.FK)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(record => record.Date).First());
```

Comment: Did work perfectly! My project is .NET 4.5.2 and for OrderByDescending ... I had to change first() to FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @Manu There must always be at least 1 item in each group, so `First` should be sufficient.

Comment: With first() I do get an errror at runtime and I guess it is because there are records where Date = null.